# List view not updating in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, listview, xpath

I am trying to display playlist information from a web service into a list View object using VB.net

I have managed to get the XML from the service and turn it into Strings and created a loop to enter the information into the list view. The problem is that it is always entering the information from the first song several times

[image]
The result from the web service is shown here

[image]

The console log from inside the for loop is:

```
<name>Test Song one</name><artist>The tested</artist><album>To test</album>
<name>Test two</name><artist>the Tested</artist><album>To test</album>
<name>Test 3</name><artist>Tested</artist><album>To test</album>
```

Here is the code from this method:

```
        serviceReturn = service.getList(txtPlaylist.Text)
        MessageBox.Show(serviceReturn)
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument

        Dim result As XmlElement = doc.CreateElement("playlist")
        result.InnerXml = serviceReturn
        Dim lstName As XmlNode = result.SelectSingleNode("/name")

        Dim results As XmlNodeList
        results = result.GetElementsByTagName("song")
        lstSong.Items.Add(lstName.InnerText)
        Dim songNod As XmlNode
        Dim listName As ListViewItem
        For Each songNod In results
            listName = New ListViewItem
            Console.WriteLine(songNod.InnerXml)
            Dim lstSongName As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("/song/name")
            Dim lstSongArtist As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("/song/artist")
            Dim lstSongAlbum As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("/song/album")

            listName = New ListViewItem(lstSongName.InnerText)
            listName.SubItems.Add(lstSongArtist.InnerText)
            listName.SubItems.Add(lstSongAlbum.InnerText)
            detailedView.Items.Add(listName)
            listName = Nothing
            lstSongName = Nothing
            lstSongArtist = Nothing
            lstSongAlbum = Nothing

        Next
```

Could anyone point out why it's just printing the first song every time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to add NEW ListViewItems - add `listName = New ListViewItem` to the start of the For/Each loop

Comment: i tried this, i got the same output when i ran the program

Comment: i added this new line to the code above just before console.writeLine()

Comment: sorry didnt see it there in between outages (if it was there) - get rid of the `listName = Nothing` line - they are objects so you dont want to kill the one you just added.  (you have 2 NEWS in there now)

Comment: is it bad that i have 2 New's?

Comment: i removed the listName = Nothing line, same result

Comment: make sure results isn't the first item three times. It could be a read issue, and not the listview.

Comment: set a breakpoint and see if `lstSongName` does change in the loop.  The SO outages are making it hard to follow.

Comment: I would point out that I prefer to bind the listview to a list or a dataset instead of writing out all the items and subitems. Less chance for mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your XPath expression in this way

```
    Dim lstSongName As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("./name")
    Dim lstSongArtist As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("./artist")
    Dim lstSongAlbum As XmlNode = songNod.SelectSingleNode("./album")
```

You need to reference the current node, as you do now you reference always the same first node from `/playlist/song`